# What is the meaning of..."and as many centuries"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In the book *Pinocchio in Venice* by Robert Coover, there's this sentence:

> On a winter evening of the year 19—, after arduous travels across two continents ***and as many centuries...***

What does "and as many centuries" means?

Comment: _As many_ refers to _five countries_. It's short for _I've travelled across five countries and across five centuries (yes, as many centuries as countries!)_

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the word 'context'. Context is something that you provide to us to help us in answering the question. E.g. - where you found the sentence and who the author is.

Answer (score 1):

"As many" in this context means "the same number as before".  So in this context, your sentence equals

```
I have travelled across five countries and across five centuries.
```

It is probably a hyperbolic statement, meant to suggest that the speaker has been travelling for a very long time.

Comment: Travelled across five centuries might be visiting historical sites (Egypt to Greece perhaps) or technological levels of cultures (Amazon tribes to modern). But without context who knows? It might be Dr Who.

Comment: @Avon That's a good point -- I hadn't considered the historical interpretation.  That sounds more likely to me now.

Comment: Hellion has found the source and corrected the quote to *two continents and as many centuries* and it is a story about "Pinocchio, former puppet, now a 100-year-old author, returns to Venice to finish a book" (from [NY Times book review](https://www.nytimes.com/books/98/09/27/specials/coover-venice.html)) so it appears both of our speculations were wrong: it is just literal.